# Helm Chart Labels and Selectors

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I create a helm chart with `helm create`command for Helm v3 and it creates for me standart template.Because of I am new to using Helm, I have some confusion to use selector and labels.

So how should use the labels between the deployment.yaml and services.yaml?

Use `include-road-dashboard.labels` command already do the same thing as below or I need to specify the labels separate like as below command. My question is same as well for `{{ include "road-dashboard.selectorLabels" . }}` command.

**Updated Template**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {{ include "road-dashboard.fullname" . }}
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: {{ include "road-dashboard.name" . }}
    helm.sh/chart: {{ include "road-dashboard.chart" . }}
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: {{ .Release.Name }}
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: {{ .Release.Service }}
```

---

**Helm Standart Template**

**deployment.yaml**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {{ include "road-dashboard.fullname" . }}
  labels:
    {{- include "road-dashboard.labels" . | nindent 4 }}
spec:
  replicas: {{ .Values.replicaCount }}
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      {{- include "road-dashboard.selectorLabels" . | nindent 6 }}
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        {{- include "road-dashboard.selectorLabels" . | nindent 8 }}
    spec:
```

**service.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: {{ include "road-dashboard.fullname" . }}
  labels:
    {{- include "road-dashboard.labels" . | nindent 4 }}
spec:
  type: {{ .Values.service.type }}
  ports:
    - port: {{ .Values.service.port }}
      targetPort: http
      protocol: TCP
      name: http
  selector:
    {{- include "road-dashboard.selectorLabels" . | nindent 4 }}
```

**-helpers.tpl**

```
  {{/*
Common labels
*/}}
{{- define "road-dashboard.labels" -}}
helm.sh/chart: {{ include "road-dashboard.chart" . }}
{{ include "road-dashboard.selectorLabels" . }}
{{- if .Chart.AppVersion }}
app.kubernetes.io/version: {{ .Chart.AppVersion | quote }}
{{- end }}
app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: {{ .Release.Service }}
{{- end -}}

{{/*
Selector labels
*/}}
{{- define "road-dashboard.selectorLabels" -}}
app.kubernetes.io/name: {{ include "road-dashboard.name" . }}
app.kubernetes.io/instance: {{ .Release.Name }}
{{- end -}}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You continue using the ones you created in the `helpers.tpl` and use the Deployment/service/any resource or you use the one you posted in the beginning.

just a comment in your `helpers.tpl`
in the `define "road-dashboard.labels"` is missing the `app.kubernetes.io/name` and `app.kubernetes.io/instance` you should add there as well otherwise the selector will not work

you also can check this documentation for guidelines: https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/REVIEW_GUIDELINES.md#names-and-labels

Comment: Thanks for your answering cpanato.. So which usage is much more convenient do you think?

Comment: using the helper makes cleaner, but then if you need to check the label you will need to open the helpers.tpl to check. it is a choice, I don't have a preference

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. Just for your comments, if I define selector separately then I guess no necessary to add them into 'define "road-dashboard.labels'